# SimpleDateFormat.parse(String) gives null value android

Tags: java, android, null, datetime-format

I am working on android application in which i am parsing date and time in UTC by using `SimpleDateFormat` but the problem is that on parsing that string i am getting the null value. My code is given below, along with the date which i got from date pickers.

```
// It is the date which i get it from pickers mDateSelected = 6/24/2015 4:07:00 PM
Date myDate = null;
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                try {

                // Here i am getting null Value ar myDate   
                    myDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(mDateSelected);



                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();

                }
```

Comment: Where is this mDateSelected came from?

Comment: it seems you have comment the line of mDateSelected.

Comment: @Selvin boss i am not using sock-puppet account for any serial upvotes. Do not underestimate here please. I have just post my question here, if you have any problem then kindly mark it for the modirators

Comment: @Amy mDateSelected is the value which is coming from my date picker.

Answer (score 2):

your `SimpleDateFormat` pattern is wrong. Since you have a date in the format

```
6/24/2015 4:07:00 PM
```

it should be

```
m/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a
```

and not

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer here. Actually now the problem is that it is not setting the time according to UTC format, like it is adding 4 + hours to the selected date here after the formatting. My date format is now like Fri Jan 23 20:51:13 GMT+04:00 2015

Answer (score 0):

use these code following below

```
    String Todaydate;
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Todaydate = df.format(new java.util.Date());
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Log.d("Current Date", Todaydate);
```